# InterstitialAd failed to load: LoadAdError(code: 0, domain: com.google.android.gms.ad

Tags: java, flutter, dart, admob, flutter-test

[this is main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xv7fm.png)

[this is my home page on Tap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dmjgf.png)

Comment: Hey @faizy 313 welcome to stack overflow, in order to get answers quickly you need to share more details please take a look of this to learn how to ask goog question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

> **Error Code 0 : ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR**
>
> This indicates that something happened internally; for instance, an
> invalid response was received from the ad server.
>
> Newly created Ad Units can take upto 2 hours to become active (SpinUp
> Time). Any Ad requests from newly created Ad Units would also receive
> Error Code 0 in response to Ad requests until they are ready to serve
> live ads.

From **Admob** Documentation for further details click this link below
https://support.google.com/admob/thread/3494603/admob-error-codes-logs?hl=en